# JQuery slide single item per element

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm writing a jQuery code that slides in a child div on hover. Because I have several child elements under that class, there is a problem that on hover any parent element, all child elements show even for elements that have not been hovered. I want to  slide the div containing the text when the parent element is hovered. my sample code is here and a fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ndfWm/)

Css is here

```
.artistAndVideo {
    background-color: black;
    display: none;
    color: white;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    width: 211px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

HTML

```
 <div id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-ie7">
                <ul>
    <li><div style="overflow:hidden;"><img src="image.png" width="211" height="170"/><div class="artistAndVideo"><span style="opacity:1;">some stuff here<span></div></div>';
        <div style="overflow:hidden;"><img src="image.png" width="211" height="170" /><div class="artistAndVideo"><span style="opacity:1;">some stuff here<span></div></div>';
      </li><li>  <div style="overflow:hidden;"><img src="image.png" width="211" height="170" /><div class="artistAndVideo"><span style="opacity:1;">some stuff here<span></div></div>';
   </li>  </ul>
            </div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#mycarousel").hover(function(){                  
                    $('.artistAndVideo').slideToggle();
                });
```

Comment: please create a jsfiddle

Comment: your html is out of whack. you should not nest divs directly inside an unordered list. UL should contain LI. I am not sure, what you are trying to achieve. A fiddle would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $("#mycarousel li").hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.artistAndVideo').stop(true,true).animate({ top : -45});
    },function () {
     $(this).find('.artistAndVideo').stop(true,true).animate({ top : -5});
 });
```

Html : All Elements inside a `ul` must be inside an `li`

```
<div id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-ie7">
<ul>
    <li>
        <div style="overflow:hidden;height:170px;margin-bottom:10px">
            <img src="image.png" width="211" height="170" />
            <div class="artistAndVideo"><span style="opacity:1;">some stuff here</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div style="overflow:hidden;;height:170px;margin-bottom:10px">
            <img src="image.png" width="211" height="170" />
            <div class="artistAndVideo"><span style="opacity:1;">some stuff here</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div style="overflow:hidden;;height:170px;margin-bottom:10px">
            <img src="image.png" width="211" height="170" />
            <div class="artistAndVideo"><span style="opacity:1;">some stuff here</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.artistAndVideo {
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  width: 211px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  opacity:0.4;
  filter:alpha(opacity=40);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ndfWm/2/)**

Comment: I added the <li></li> tags but still same problem.